# Mocking a callback passed as parameter into an object

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a modal service that I try to test but unfortunately I don't know how I'm supposed to mock the callbacks «ok» and «cancel» passed as parameters to the service. My unit test pass, but the coverage needs some love:

My component class:

```
export class TestComponent {

    constructor(private _modalService : ModalService) {}

    public show() : void {
        this._modalService.showModal(DefaultModalComponent, {
            ok: () => {
                alert("Ok have been clicked.");
                this._modalService.hide();
            },
            cancel: () => {
                alert("Cancel have been clicked.");
                this._modalService.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My unit test class look like this:

```
describe("TestComponent", () => {

    let _modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj("ModalService", ["show"]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: ModalService, useValue: _modalService }]
        });
     });

     let _component: any;
     let _element: any;

     beforeEach(done => {
         TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
             let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
             fixture.detectChanges();
             _component = fixture.componentInstance;
             _element = fixture.nativeElement;

             done();
         });
     });

    describe("show()", () => {
        it("should have called show method from service with parameters provided", done => {
            _component.show();

            expect(_modalService.show).toHaveBeenCalled();

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service can be refactored in test-friendly way:

```
modalOkHandler = () => { ... }

modalCancelHandler = () => { ... }

public show() : void {
    this._modalService.showModal(DefaultModalComponent, {
        ok: this.modalOkHandler,
        cancel: this.modalCancelHandler
    });
}
```

This way the callbacks can be asserted on called method:

```
_component.show();
expect(_modalService.show).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DefaultModalComponent, {
  ok: modalService.modalOkHandler,
  cancel: modalService.modalCancelHandler
});
```

The alternative is less convenient. For anonymous functions, method arguments should be tested instead:

```
_component.show();
expect(_modalService.show).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DefaultModalComponent, {
  ok: jasmine.any(Function),
  cancel: jasmine.any(Function)
});

const [, { ok, cancel }] = _component.show.calls.first().args;
spyOn(window, 'alert');
expect(_modalService.hide).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
ok();
expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
expect(_modalService.hide).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
...
```